# Access Token for SharePoint REST API calls through AAD?

Tags: azure, .net-core, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently building a .NET Core App which performs direct SharePoint REST calls to:  contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/shipment/_api/search/query?querytext='...'

The .NET Core App is registerd in the Application Registrations. How do I retrieve the Access Token? (For some reason MS Graph API is not able to make these calls, hence trying SPO REST API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the certificate way to get the token like this:

```
    private static async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        string applicationId = "xxx";
        string tenantId = "contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\certificate.pfx", "password");

        IConfidentialClientApplication confApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(applicationId)
        .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}")
        .WithCertificate(certificate) // This is just a local method that gets the certificate on my machine
        .Build();

        var scopes = new[] { "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/.default" };
        var authenticationResult = await confApp.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following code for public client application

```
public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
{
    var clientId = "{client_id}";
    var tenantId = "{tenant_id}";
    var instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
    IPublicClientApplication clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority($"{instance}/{tenantId}")
                .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                .Build();

    var accounts = await clientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
    var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

    var scopes = new[] { "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/.default" };
    var userName = "{user}";
    SecureString password = ...;
    AuthenticationResult authResult;
    try
    {
        authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount).ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
    {
        authResult = await clientApp
                    .AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, userName, password)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
    }
    return authResult.AccessToken;
}
```